# Use regular expressions in Visual Studio to match (non-consecutive) and replace recurring string in an expression

Tags: regex, visual-studio

I am tasked to refactor namespaces in vs2015 Solution, removing duplicate/repeating words.

1. I need a **FIND** regex that returns these namespaces and everywhere that may have been used or referenced.
2. I need replace regex to remove the second occurrence of the word from namespace.

EXAMPLE
          TestApp.SA.TestApp => TestApp.SA
          TestApp.TestApp.SA => TestApp.SA

Here is my regex to Find(which I know can be better) : TestApp.*?(TestApp)

Somebody please help with an expression for replace, which I think is to set the second occurrence of TestApp to whiteSpace ?

Comment: To find them, you might try `(\w+)\.(\w+\.)*\1`. To S&R those, try [`(\w+)((?:\.\w+)*)\.\1` and replace with `$1$2`](https://regex101.com/r/DqPq2V/1).

Comment: Thanks so much this works, I just think I need to refine the find expression, I returns some unwanted results like digits. An example is it find 1.0.0.0 and after replace I get 1.0.0. Thanks a mili for the instant help.

Comment: Yes, you need to use `([A-Z]\w*)\.([A-Za-z_]\w*\.)*\1` or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The patterns I will suggest are not a 100% safe solution, but will show you a way to use regex for search and search and replace in your files.

The basic expressions you may use for the task are

```
(\w+)\.(\w+\.)*\1
```

and

```
Find:     (\w+)((?:\.\w+)*)\.\1
Replace:  $1$2
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DqPq2V/1)

The patterns mean:

- `(\w+)` - match and capture 1+ alphanumeric/underscore chars into Group 1
- `\.` - matches a literal dot
- `(\w+\.)*` - zero or more sequences (`(...)*`) of 1+ word chars followed with a dot (each subsequent submatch  will erase the Group 2 buffer, but it is not important when just searching)
- `\1` - a [**backreference**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) to the contents captured in Group 1

The second pattern is almost the same, just the capturing groups are a bit adjusted for the [replacement numbered backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) to replace text correctly.